# How to handle sessions securely in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I'm fairly new to SvelteKit and I'm wondering how to properly handle sessions. From what I understand a unique session ID is typically stored in the browser as a cookie and this is linked to the currently signed in user backend. I'm used to PHP where all this is taken care of for you but that doesn't seem to be the case with SvelteKit.

This is what I've got so far:

/src/hooks.ts:

```
import cookie from 'cookie';
import { v4 as uuid } from '@lukeed/uuid';
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { getOrCreateSession } from '$lib/Authentication';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '');
    event.locals.userid = cookies.userid || uuid();

    const response = await resolve(event);

    if (!cookies.userid) {
        // if this is the first time the user has visited this app,
        // set a cookie so that we recognise them when they return
        response.headers.set(
            'set-cookie',
            cookie.serialize('userid', event.locals.userid, {
                path: '/',
                httpOnly: true
            })
        );
    }

    return response;
};

export async function getSession(event) : Promise<App.Session> {
    return getOrCreateSession(event.locals.userid);
}
```

/src/app.d.ts:

```
/// <reference types="@sveltejs/kit" />

// See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#the-app-namespace
// for information about these interfaces
declare namespace App {
    interface Locals {
        userid: string;
    }

    // interface Platform {}

    interface Session {
        id: string;
        userId?: number;
    }

    // interface Stuff {}
}
```

/src/lib/Authentication.ts:

```
export let sessions: App.Session[] = [];

export async function getOrCreateSession(id: string) {
    let session = sessions.find(x => x.id === id);
    if(!session) {
        session = {
            id: id,
        };
        sessions.push(session);
    }
    return session;
}
```

/src/routes/setSession.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    export async function load({ session }) {
        session.userId = 1;
        return {}
    }
</script>
```

/src/routes/getSession.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    export async function load({ fetch, session }) {
        return {
            props: {
                session: session,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script lang="ts">
    export let session: App.Session;
</script>
{JSON.stringify(session)}
```

Visiting /setSession will set `userId` and it'll be retrieved when visiting /getSession.

1. Is this the proper way to do this?
2. Other than sessions not persisting on server restart, is there any other drawback storing the sessions in a variable instead of a database?
3. Over time `sessions` will become quite large. To have an expiry date that's extended on each request would probably be a good idea but where would be a good place to put the code that remove all expired sessions?

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to sveltekit and I believe that sveltekit server side is typically stateless so that it can be deployed on edge functions.

One way to manage sessions, would be to store all session data in an HTTP only cookie (not only the session ID). This is the idea of [svelte-kit-cookie-session](https://github.com/pixelmund/svelte-kit-cookie-session)

Of course, you can also use a database to store session data.

To manage expiration:

1. If you store session data in a cookie, then set the `expires` parameter on the creation
2. If you store session data in a database, depending on the database, you might use a Time To Live policy...